# Javascript replace expression explained

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following function:

```
function replace(path) {
    return path.replace(/\//g, '.').replace(/^\./, '');
};
```

Can you please explain what exactly is doing? I have some hard time understanding it mostly because of the slashes and escapes.

I know it replaces something with something. :)

Comment: if you have trouble with Regex, this Website is very usefull for learing the basics: http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return path.replace(/\//g, '.').replace(/^\./, '');
```

The `/` at the start and end are delimiters of regex.

The `\` inside it will escape the following character(`\` and `.`).

1. `/\//g`: Will find all(`g`: global flag) the `/` in the string and will replace it by `.`
2. `/^\./`: Will find the `.` at the `start`(`^`) of the string and will remove it

Answer (score 0):

Replace `/` with `.`, and then replace `.` at the beginning of string with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that `path` is a `string`. `string`s in javascript, like everything else, are objects. Among other things, they have a `replace` function. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Those things with the slashes are called regular expressions, or `RegEx`s for short. You can read about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [here](http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html). They are very useful and often used for manipulating `string`s with operations like `replace`.